# antd Form onSubmit or action properties not triggered

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

I have a login form where on button click data should be sent to the backend. I use ant design and on Form action attribute I am passing the service url `(action={url})` where the data will be sent. However, when I click the submit button, nothing happens. I tried changing the antd form to use  html form with antd form controllers, like Form.Item and Input components and the data get submitted. I suspect that the problem is within antd *action* attribute. How can I make an antD Form to submit the data using the action attribute?

```
           const handleSubmit = (val) => {
               console.log("Values : ", val);
           };


           <Form
              name="login"
              layout="vertical"
              autoComplete="off"
              action={url}
              method="post"
              onFinish={handleSubmit}
            >
                 <Form.Item
                      htmlFor="username"
                      label="Username"
                      name="username"
                      rules={[
                        {
                          required: true,
                          message: `Please input your username!`,
                        },
                      ]}
                    >

                  <Input/>
               </Form.Item>
               <Form.Item
                      htmlFor="password"
                      label="Password"
                      name="password"
                      rules={[
                        {
                          required: true,
                          message: `Please input your password!`,
                        },
                      ]}
                    >

                  <Input.Password/>
               </Form.Item>
               <Button
                  size="large"
                  htmlType="submit"
                  name="login"
                  id="login-btn"
                >
                  Login
                </Button>
          </Form>
```

Comment: you can call the url with form data inside the handle submit function. No need to set action, method attributes in Form. Is there any reason to use that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send the request inside your `handleSubmit` function using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) or an HTTP client like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) (recommended).
An example with axios:

```js
const handleSubmit = (values) => {
 axios.post(url,values).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
 }).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
 })
};
```